# send data with serial send block in Simulink to Arduiino

Tags: matlab, arduino, simulink

I'm trying to send and receive data through a serial port using simulink matlab and Arduino. when to receive data from Arduino to simulink matlab no problem!!
but for sent data to Arduino, I'm faced with this error.

[image]

and simulation simulink picture is:

[image]

Comment: I'm faced with this error.   " Complex signal mismatch. Input port 2 of 'SerialArduino_simulink/Sum' expects a signal of numeric type real. However, it is driven by a signal of numeric type complex
Component: Simulink | Category: Block error
Complex signal mismatch. Output 'y' is a signal of numeric type complex. However, it is driving a signal of numeric type real. "

Comment: Does [this](https://in.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/sssetinputportcomplexsignal.html) and [this](https://in.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/sssetoutputportcomplexsignal.html) help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation `double (c)` on the output `y` from your MATLAB Function block indicates that the signal is numerically complex, see [Display Signal Attributes](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/displaying-signal-properties.html) in the documentation for more details. This is the source of your problem, as mentioned in the error message (which is pretty self-explanatory by the way).

To fix it, you need to specify the data type of your outputs to be real in the [Ports and Data Manager](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/matlab-function-block-editor.html#bqgwvsq-1).

Alternatively, you can add a [Complex to Real-Imag](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/complextorealimag.html) to the output(s) of your MATLAB Function block and take only the real or imaginary part of the signal, depending on what you want your algorithm to do.